# GEB: set default environment?

Tags: groovy, automation, automated-tests, geb

I declared a few environments in GebConfig via `environments {}` closure.
And if I specify `-Dgeb.env` in command line, everything works perfectly.

But when I start a single test for debugging purposes, I don't want to explicitly pass any additional environment variables.

What is the way to define the environment to be used by GEB as a default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define a default `driver` outside of the `environments` My Geb config looks like this:

```java
driver = {
  new HtmlUnitDriver(true)
}

environments {
  html_unit {
    driver = {
      new HtmlUnitDriver(true)
    }
  }
  phantomjs {
    driver = {
      WebDriverManager.phantomjs().version("2.1.1").setup()
      def pjsDriver = new PhantomJSDriver()
      pjsDriver.manage().window().size = new Dimension(1024, 768)
      pjsDriver
    }
  }
  chrome {
    driver = {
      // (...)
    }
  }
  chrome_headless {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", "chromedriver.log")
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging", "true")
    driver = {
      // (...)
    }
  }
  firefox {
    driver = {
      // (...)
    }
  }
  ie {
    driver = {
      // (...)
    }
  }
  edge {
    driver = {
      // (...)
    }
  }
  opera {
    driver = {
      // (...)
    }
  }
  win_app {
    driver = {
      // (...)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As a suggested, whatever you specify outside of the `environments` block will be used when no geb environment is set. So basically unwrap and move whatever config you have for the environment you want to be default outside of the `environments` block and job done. The mechanism underpinning the `GebConfig` script is Groovy's `ConfigSlurper` which is described at https://blog.mrhaki.com/2009/10/groovy-goodness-using-configslurper.html.